# cygwin version of idle has erroneous I/O handling

Tags: cygwin, python-idle, python-2.5

I am using idle (python 2.5) via cygwin on a windows vista machine and when I try to open an already existing .py file I see the full file path

```
/home/aaron/C:/cygwin/home/aaron/script.py
```

on the banner of the freshly openned file window when I expect simply

```
/home/aaron/script.py
```

In addition, the file appears blank which makes sense...basically idle is opening up a nonexistent file in some fictitious path.  So what is causing the problem and how to fix?  Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I found a workaround is to use `File->Path Browser` menu. From there I can find the `.py` file and open it by double clicking the file name.